# iOS 10 Music App: "Add to up Next"?

Tags: music, music.app, ios

The **iOS 10 Music** app is revised and I had to get used to the new layout, thus investing *some* time in finding things.

However, I am pretty clueless on where to find the `Add to Up Next` feature. There is the `Play Next` feature, but this doesn't allow me to add the selected song to the bottom of the queue. Using this on selected songs will essentially **reverse** the order of selected songs.

Where can I find the `Add to Up Next` feature on **iOS 10 Music** app?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That option does not appear to be present in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the way the iOS 10 Music app handles this. However, there is a workaround that will get you by until Apple fixes it.

Take these steps:

1. Go into the Up Next screen
2. Turn off the *Shuffle* function
3. Completely close down the Music App (don't just exit)
4. Launch the Music App again
5. Use 3D Touch (press firmly) on a song and select the *Play Next* option
6. Now use 3D Touch again, but on another song, and you'll see the *Play Later* option.
7. Select *Play Later* to add that song to the bottom of your Up Next queue.
8. Now the *Play Later* option will be there for all following songs.

However, the reason this is a workaround is that:

- you no longer have the *Shuffle* function available to you.
- I'm not sure what the workaround is if you have a device without 3D Touch

To have this whole issue fixed, [send feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/apple-music.html).

Comment: I don't use shuffle. But after using `Play Next` once, the option `Play Later` doesn't appear.

Comment: Hmmm, pretty sure I didn't miss a step. Just confirming - at Step 3 did you completely exit the Music app by double-pressing the Home button and swiping up on the app?

Comment: Interesting. I just turned shuffle on and **then** off. After step 3 and skipping step 5, it works. Must be a bug so we should expect it to get fixed. Until then, this is a great workaround! +1

Comment: Good to know, Hopefully this helps others out! Oh, and make sure you send Apple some feedback about this.

Comment: 3D Touch? What is that? (iPhone SE user).

Comment: 3D Touch is the process of _pressing firmly_ on the screen. This is not the typical _long press_ you're familiar with for Copy, Paste, etc. To familiarise yourself, do this test: On the Home screen, _long press_ on the Clock icon and you'll notice that it wiggles. Press the Home button to stop the wiggling. Now, _press firmly_ on the Clock icon. This triggers the 3D Touch and you'll actually feel the response and see some options. It's a bit like right-clicking with a mouse. 3D Touch can be used on many apps, both on the Home Screen (Settings etc) and within the apps (Mail etc) themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I have an iPhone 6 and all I had to do was quit the app, add a song using Play Next, then I could add any songs I wanted using Play Later. I think the Play Later feature doesn't show if you just press on a song to play instantly, because I pressed on a song in my playlist and it adds all the other songs after it in that playlist into the Up Next list.